# Unable to see provisioning profile in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I am trying to enable push for an existing app have in the App Store.

I have not used a wildcard app id, but a specific app id.

I followed this tutorial for creating certificates, https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

When i try to create new `App ID` in `Apple Developer Member Center` it is asking for `Bundle ID`, when i enter my app `Bundle ID` it shows `Bundle ID already taken`

so, i tried to enable to push notification in my exiting app id, and created new provisions profile.

I am able to do this, but it doesn't show my provisioning profile in Xcode Under Project, "Build Settings", and inside the "Code Signing Identity"

and also i am unable to delete my existing `App ID` so that i can create new `App ID`.

While deleting it shows,**The App ID '49TBXXXX6U.com.MYAPP' exists in the App Store so it cannot be removed.**

**Where i am making mistake ? why it is doesn't shows my profile in Xcode**

**Please help and Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to enable push for an existing app you have in the App Store.

The app seems not to have used a wildcard app id, but a specific app id. If that is so, you must select the app id and continue from your step 1.3.

If this is not the case, it just seems you need to let XCode sync up the provisioning profiles. You do that from the XCode menu / Preferences / Accounts / View Details / Refresh (icon)

If all else fails, check [Apples App Distribution Guide / Configuring Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH32-SW1)

Comment: Yes, you right bro i am trying t  enable push notfication  for an existing app in the App Store, i have not used wildcard app id also i have created new provisioning profile but it doesn't show up in Xcode :(

Comment: Can i create a new AppID that used the same bundle identifier as the original app ?